# Reflection Emit. Generalizing Ldc_R8 and Ldc_I4_0

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, metaprogramming, reflection.emit

I have metaprogramm, that needs to create code for initializing value fields.
I.e. have class

```
class Class1
{
    int i;
    double t;
    Class1()
    {
       i=5;
       t=3;
    }
}
```

In reflection this looks like follow:

```
...
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4,5);
...
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8,3);
...
```

I don't want to have a huge switch like this:

```
switch(t)
{
case typeof(int): gen.Emit(OpCode.Ldc_I4,value); break;
case typeof(double): gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8,value); break;
// and so on for all value types
}
```

Is there some universal load value on evaluation stack OpCode? Or I need to have switch mentioned above?

Comment: Surely `float` is not `R8`! Did you mean `double`?

Comment: You'll need the giant switch, and please post it here where you're done so that others can use it :)

Comment: BTW, you only have a finite range to deal with, I dont see the problem coding a big switch. Do it once and you are done!

Comment: You don't have to initialize local variables, the CLR initializes them to 0.

Comment: Hans is right - CLR guarantees that local variables are automatically zeroed. Thus, there's no point in these assignments at all.

Comment: @HansPassant: Is that always the case with Reflection.Emit? I can't see a way to 'disable' `.init` of the locals.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: That is not the case with the CLR, but possibly with Reflection.Emit. See my comment above.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes I know about this. But what if the value is dynamically generated? See my edits.

Comment: @All: Sorry for my first question. I specialized it. See my edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both fields and local variables start at zero by default, so you likely don't need this.

For setting a variable to its default value, you can use `ldloca <variable>` followed by `initobj <type>`.
`initobj` is normally used for structs (`default(MyStruct)` in C#), but it should also work for primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using .Net expression trees instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/08/10/expression-trees-take-two-introducing-system-linq-expressions-v4-0.aspx

Comment: How can I use expression trees for generating a library with dynamically created code?

Comment: @zabulus With the `CompileToMethod`-method but you can only compile the expressions into `static` methods. So you can't use this for variable initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method built-in. You can create a helper by yourself and have the problem solved for all time.

That said, you can use expression trees and have the emit code into an ILGenerator of your choice. This means you can generate not only dynamic methods but use them to fill your TypeBuilder-created methods.